# make div under div same width as parent even if its children larger its parent

Tags: css, flexbox

https://jsfiddle.net/h7j1wz9m/

I want this:
[image: current beahvior]

to behave like this:
[image: desired behavior]

The challenge I am facing is how to set the width of `div#listWrapper` in https://jsfiddle.net/h7j1wz9m/ so that it has the same width as `div#right` and does **not** grow with its contents.

Comment: min-width: 0; to div#right